# Using Django 3+ on older Postgres (9.4)

Tags: django, postgresql-9.4

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822805/how-to-use-django-2-2-with-legacy-postgresql-8-4-database), I need to use a newer Django (v3.1) application on an older Postgres database (v9.4). The solutions in this article (upgrading, migrating data to new database) are the better advice, but for the short-term, I would prefer this work with these versions (even though Django 3 dropped support for 9.4).

One issue at least is that `ON CONFLICT`, a newer feature in Postgres v9.5, is used by Django for manytomany management, so a simple `.add()` call includes this SQL.

Comment: 9.4 is at the end of life (7 years old) and security fixes for it are no longer available. Using end of life version is generally  highly insecure practice

Comment: This environment happens to be isolated and hopefully upgraded soon, but definitely solid advice

Answer (score 1):

The hacky (short-term) solution, which may run into other issues down the line, was to disable the `ignore_conflicts` feature in the Django database backend.  This was accomplished as follows:

1. Create new module for custom backend:

   ```sh
   # Here I'm assuming there is a 'core' module in the project;
   # a common alternative is to see the project name for this module ('<project>/db')
   cd <project>
   mkdir -p core/db
   touch core/db/__init__.py
   ```
2. Custom backend classes in `core/db/base.py` to disable this feature:

   ```py
   from django.db.backends.postgresql.base import DatabaseWrapper as PgDatabaseWrapper
   from django.db.backends.postgresql.features import DatabaseFeatures as PgDatabaseFeatures


   class DatabaseFeatures(PgDatabaseFeatures):
       supports_ignore_conflicts = False


   class DatabaseWrapper(PgDatabaseWrapper):
       features_class = DatabaseFeatures
   ```
3. Update database config in settings to use new backend:

   ```
   # in settings.py
   DATABASES = {
       "default": {
           "ENGINE": "core.db",
           # ... rest of postgres settings ...
       }
   }
   ```